# Via and its usage

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

We had a discussion over over the correct usage and meaning of the following sentences.

> Sign up **via** (web.link) or **calling** (phone number) by DD MMM ‘YY.

vs.

> Sign up **via** (web.link) or **call** (phone number) by DD MMM ‘YY.

Which would be the correct usage if the intention is the ability to sign up via both methods? Are either or both correct? Is there a difference in meaning?

Cheers to everyone for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The first one isn't grammatical, the second one is but doesn't convey the meaning you want.

> Sign up via (web.link) or call (phone number) by DD MMM ‘YY.

Means that you can either "sign up via link" or "call phone number". 
What you want to say is:

> Sign up **via** (link) or **by** calling (phone number) by DD MM YYYY.